# changing the url click button configuration from (alt + mouse left click) in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

since the **alt + mouse left click** has been assigned to **window move** in **linux** I cannot open the url links in vscode.

I want to change it from **alt** to something else. I could not find it in the **settings** as well as **keyboard shortcuts** section.

Any idea how do it?

Comment: Watch this video

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/introvideos/customize

Comment: it is the opposite of the [MultiCursor Modifier](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_multicursor-modifier)